# Why does the 1 px pencil tool draw 2 pixels?

Tags: pixel, photoshop

In photoshop cs 6, the 1 px pencil tool is drawing a 1x2 square.  The square that I click on, and the square to the right.

Answer (score 1):

Another good thing to do to the pencil tool in case you get wrong tool proportions - 
Reset the tool:

- After choosing the pencil tool, click on the pencil's icon drop down arrow which is on the top left corner of the screen.
- Click on the little Settings icon which is on the top right of the popped up window.
- Choose Reset Tool.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Photoshop was correcting for my view resolution in an unexpected way.

Go to View -> Pixel aspect ratio and select square to turn pixels back into pixels when zoomed in.